# Can't login: user/login redirects to live site

Tags: users

I copied a live site built by a previous developer to my local MAMP environment, and discovered that trying to use /user/login redirected me to the live site. I discovered that .htaccess had numerous **dreaded** 301 redirects. So, I changed the .htaccess to a clean one, cleared cache, cleared history, rebooted MAMP, tried a clean browser. I think I've now cleared the 301 redirects to regular pages, but user/login still goes to the live site.

Created fresh local install with a clean .htaccess; clear cache, reboot MAMP, etc, still can't login to local.

Is there a backend way to login to drupal? Through drush?

Could that demon-spawn developer have set something else that prevents local login?

Comment: Is it using the secure pages module, is the base URL set in settings.php?

Comment: Yes, Thank you. The secure pages module: drush dis securepages

Answer (score 3):

If the live site uses HTTPS, implements SSL, try to check if is using modules like [secure_pages](https://drupal.org/project/securepages). This kind of modules sometimes causes that kind of redirections.

Another thing to check could be the settings.php to see if there are something related to this issue.

Comment: Thank you Gerzensti & Jsheffers. It was in fact the Secure Pages module. Disabled that with Drush, and I was golden. I was looking in this direction already from a suggestion on another problem to look at Securelogin module.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Domain or something like this, what I did (on Windows) was editing the "hosts" file to redirect the production site URL (http://www.production.com) to 127.0.0.1.

So all your requests to your production site will be redirected to localhost.

After that, edit your domain settings to set the domain to 127.0.0.1 (or the URL you access your development website).

Finally, delete the redirection in hosts file.

I would also suggest to check for custom modules and clear cache with drush.

Answer (score 0):

Another module that can cause this problem is Ubercart SSL.  I was being redirected when attempting to login and it took me a while to figure out which module was the culprit.  `drush dis uc_ssl` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If Secure page causing the issue then you can disable it with following ways

1) Drush command

**drush dis -y securepages**

2) Disable the status in DB

**UPDATE system SET STATUS =0 WHERE name =  'securepages'**